# Pair string lengths to strings from unordered list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers and strings of different lengths.  I want to generate a dictionary mapping each number to the string with that length, discarding numbers and strings if they don't have a pair.

```
py_list = ['1', '##', '2', '#', '3', '####', '4', '###', '5', '######']
py_dict = {'1': '#', '2': '##', '3': '###', '4': "####"}
```

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Iterate through the list to separate numbers into a new list
2. Iterate through the list to separate '#' strings into a new list
3. Iterate over the new lists to build the dict

I know this isn't the most efficient solution.  What is a better way to do this?

Comment: What aspects of the problem are you finding easy or difficult to solve? The site doesn't really like "give the me the code" questions, so you need to be specific what you're asking. Then answers can avoid wasting time on things you don't need.

Comment: ... doing so also usually results in a question that's more useful for future visitors to the site, since they're more likely to suffer from the same more restricted problem you're having with this task, than they are to need to complete this exact task.

Comment: @steve-jessop - I have updated my post with the steps that I have been upto  to get the results. Sometime its difficult to post the code as it might contain some other sensitive part of the code. **Thanks for the suggestions though**.

Comment: Are the values in `py_list` always alternative between number and the strings '##...'?

Comment: @hai-vu - it wont always be the case that number and '#' will appear alternatively in py_list.

Comment: @hai-vu - it wont always be the case that number and '#' will appear alternatively in py_list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as

```
>>> { str(len(x)) : x for x in py_list if not x.isdigit() and str(len(x)) in py_list }
{'1': '#', '3': '###', '2': '##', '4': '####'}
```

Answer (score 2):

A O(n) solution :

```
s=set(int(x) for x in py_list[::2]).intersection(len(x) for x in py_list[1::2])
d={str(x) : '#'*x  for x in s}
# {1: '#', 2: '##', 3: '###', 4: '####'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
py_list = ['1', '##', '2', '#', '3', '####', '4', '###', '5', '######']
h = lambda l: '#'*l
dict_with_matching_hashes = dict([(x, h(int(x))) for x in py_list if x.isdigit() and h(int(x)) in py_list])
print(dict_with_matching_hashes)
```

This will give you the following result:

> {'2': '##', '1': '#', '4': '####', '3': '###'}

Comment: Have you tested your solution? It generates an error.